# How to save JSON as a CLOB or JSON type in database

Tags: java, json, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

In my application, I would like to save JSON for example like that below in database without a specific fields in a model. Posted JSON should be saved as a CLOB or JSON format. Can you shortly explain me how to do it? How my @RestController and Model should look like?

```
{
color: "Blue"
miles: 100
vin: "1234"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Postgreql you can use it as jsonb data type to store in DB.
In oracle you have number of options like BLOB,CLOB or varchar2.

https://blogs.oracle.com/jsondb/storing-json-in-the-oracle-database

Comment: It's clear but how to write rest controller in spring boot which saved raw JSON in a database as a CLOB? Can you give me some example how to do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: PFB the link.you have to customize code accordingly to suit your needs .http://therealdanvega.com/blog/2017/07/05/read-json-data-spring-boot-write-database

Comment: yes but still it's not what I looking for. I want to have table in database with column id and second column with raw json.

Comment: @jocom Just create table with id as int and json column as jsonb.id will be auto increment and raw json you can pass from your spring boot controller.@ResponseBody gives response as json only.